# HADOOP INSTALLATION.Here is the log file of resource manager..Need Help

Tags: hadoop

```
2015-06-03 23:52:22,716 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.ResourceManager: Transitioning to standby state
2015-06-03 23:52:22,716 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.ResourceManager: Transitioned to standby state
2015-06-03 23:52:22,716 FATAL org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.ResourceManager: Error starting ResourceManager
org.apache.hadoop.yarn.exceptions.YarnRuntimeException: java.io.IOException: Failed on local exception: java.net.SocketException: Unresolved address; Host Details : local host is: "master"; destination host is: (unknown):0;
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.factories.impl.pb.RpcServerFactoryPBImpl.getServer(RpcServerFactoryPBImpl.java:139)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.ipc.HadoopYarnProtoRPC.getServer(HadoopYarnProtoRPC.java:65)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.ipc.YarnRPC.getServer(YarnRPC.java:54)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.ResourceTrackerService.serviceStart(ResourceTrackerService.java:162)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.start(AbstractService.java:193)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.CompositeService.serviceStart(CompositeService.java:120)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.ResourceManager$RMActiveServices.serviceStart(ResourceManager.java:584)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.start(AbstractService.java:193)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.ResourceManager.startActiveServices(ResourceManager.java:999)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.ResourceManager$1.run(ResourceManager.java:1036)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.ResourceManager$1.run(ResourceManager.java:1032)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1628)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.ResourceManager.transitionToActive(ResourceManager.java:1032)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.ResourceManager.serviceStart(ResourceManager.java:1076)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.start(AbstractService.java:193)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.ResourceManager.main(ResourceManager.java:1211)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed on local exception: java.net.SocketException: Unresolved address; Host Details : local host is: "master"; destination host is: (unknown):0;
        at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.wrapException(NetUtils.java:772)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server.bind(Server.java:424)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Listener.<init>(Server.java:573)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server.<init>(Server.java:2205)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.<init>(RPC.java:931)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server.<init>(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:537)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine.getServer(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:512)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Builder.build(RPC.java:776)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.factories.impl.pb.RpcServerFactoryPBImpl.createServer(RpcServerFactoryPBImpl.java:169)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.factories.impl.pb.RpcServerFactoryPBImpl.getServer(RpcServerFactoryPBImpl.java:132)
        ... 17 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Unresolved address
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.translateToSocketException(Net.java:137)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.translateException(Net.java:163)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.translateException(Net.java:169)
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:76)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server.bind(Server.java:407)
        ... 25 more
Caused by: java.nio.channels.UnresolvedAddressException
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.checkAddress(Net.java:107)
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:217)
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
        ... 26 more
2015-06-03 23:52:22,755 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.ResourceManager: SHUTDOWN_MSG:
/************************************************************
SHUTDOWN_MSG: Shutting down ResourceManager at ubuntu/127.0.0.1
************************************************************/
```

Comment: Solved just change /etc/hosts file

Comment: Can you please write an answer, that explains your solution, so others with the same problem may find help?

Answer (score 0):

Kinda sorta solved in comments by OP

> Solved just change `/etc/hosts` file

Not sure what he changed to be honest. Will try to get more info.

Answer (score -1):

The error is given by:

> Unresolved address; Host Details : local host is: "master";
>   destination host is: (unknown):0;

which means you have to give the address of **master** in the `/etc/hosts` like so:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
...
192.168.0.110   master
```

Comment: I don't think changing the systems' hosts list is an appropriate solution if you can just tell the application to look for a different host name. -1